# VisualSVN is annoying me by asking me to enter my login & password many times

Tags: tortoisesvn, visualsvn

My VisualVSN is hooked up to Active Directory. I'm using Tortoise as the client. When I was using SVNSERVE and the text files for authentication, it only asks me for the login/password once. Now it's asking me it many times when I connect. To get around that, I would have to check the "save authentication" information checkbox. I could do that but I don't want my password stored in plaintext somewhere on my computer. Isn't there a way for me to get it to recognize the fact that I'm already logged in to my PC as a valid domain user and use my session information to authenticate me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the "save authentication" feature, your password is **not** saved in plaintext but encrypted with your logon credentials. You can check it yourself: the auth data is saved under %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth - you won't find plaintext in there (unless you're using Win9x).

Answer (score 0):

Are you aksing about VisualVSN Server or the Visual Studio plugin or both?

What protocol are you using? Try to connect to svn with https - that way it can use SSPI for authentication and you don't have to enter the password at all.